# Devo usar symbols em hashes e parâmetros para otimizar o uso de memória em Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[Nesta outra pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13264/ruby-qual-a-diferenca-de-se-usar-dois-pontos-ou-aspas-em-uma-string) eu perguntei sobre `:symbols` e `'strings'` e descobri que o uso de `:symbols` otimiza o uso de memória pela aplicação.

Minha dúvida é se o mesmo vale para a criação de hashes:

```
hash = {:indice => 'valor'}
#em vez de
hash = {indice: 'valor'}
```

E passagem de parâmetros:

```
@post = Post.find_by(:id => 1)
#em vez de
@post = Post.find_by(id: 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo [algumas](http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/memory-and-ruby-symbols/) [fontes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189416/why-use-symbols-as-hash-keys-in-ruby) você deve fazer isso **sim**.

Os símbolos são armazenados internamente em uma tabela como inteiros sem sinal, o que economiza muita memória comparando-se com o uso de strings. Em decorrência disso, a comparação entre símbolos é muito mais rápida.

Outra vantagem é que símbolos são imutáveis, enquanto strings podem ter o conteúdo alterado e "quebrar" de alguma forma o *hash*.

**Mas, sempre há efeitos colaterais.**

Um deles é que os símbolos não são coletados e residirão "eternamente" na tabela do interpretador.

O impacto será pequeno se você usar apenas símbolos explícitos no código. Porém, se usar a função [`to_sym`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_sym) para obter os símbolos correspondentes a muitas strings diferentes, principalmente se essas strings têm origem externa, o uso de memória alocada permanentemente pode aumentar consideravelmente.

---

Falando especificamente sobre o exemplo da pergunta, os trechos `hash = {:indice => 'valor'}` e `hash = {indice: 'valor'}` são equivalentes, sendo que o primeiro era usada no Ruby até a versão 1.8 e o segundo foi introduzido no ruby 1.9.

Comment: Nos links que tu passou está diferente do que eu perguntei. Nos links eles comparam `{'a' => 'b'} vs {:a => 'b'}` e eu quero saber sobre `{a: 'b'} vs {:a => 'b'}`.

Comment: @user3153542 Verdade. Eu respondi ao **título** da pergunta e não notei exatamente seu exemplo. Já adicionei a explicação na resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Não há diferença entre

```
hash = {:indice => 'valor'}    
hash = {indice: 'valor'}
```

É só "syntax sugar", e só funciona do 1.9 pra cima.

Answer (score -1):

Sempre utilizei algo ocmo

hash = { key: "value" }

Da para usar métodos como `deep_symbolize_keys` para transformar o seu hash para simbolos (mas é um método do rails)

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_symbolize_keys