# Influencia do ":" em Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, framework

Os parâmetros de validação de dados da Framework *Ruby on Rails*, usam valores com `:` antes e depois da palavra.

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { accept: true, message: 'Mensagem de Validação' }
validates :city, presence: true
```

**Como eles funcionam e que tipo de valor são?**

**Qual a diferença em `:` no começo e `:` no final da palavra?**

> **Obs: A pergunta não visa a comparação de uma *String* `"texto"` com um simbolo para uma *String* `:texto`, e sim com os símbolos `:valor` e `valor:`.**

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ruby - Qual a diferença de se usar dois pontos ou aspas em uma string?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13264/ruby-qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-de-se-usar-dois-pontos-ou-aspas-em-uma-string)

Comment: @RafaelBerro, obviamente a pergunta não é duplicada, pois não está comparando o simbolo de `string` com uma `string` mas sim o simbolo de `string` com uma chave para a propriedade de um objeto. assim como descrito na resposta abaixo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Valores que começam com : são symbols. Symbol é um tipo de dado, assim como String, Integer, Array e etc. Symbols com o mesmo mesmo nome sempre possuirão o mesmo object ID e, portanto, apontarão para um mesmo local da memória. Isso os torna mais eficazes que strings para utilização como chave em hashes, etc.

Quanto aos valores dentro de { }, com : depois do nome, são chaves de um hash. { e } delimitam o início e o fim de um hash. Cada item do hash é composto por uma chave e um valor. Além do formato { chave:'valor', outra_chave: 'outro valor'}, hashes também utilizam a sintaxe { :chave =>'valor', :outra_chave => 'outro valor'}. Em ambos os exemplos de hash, as chaves são symbols. A diferença é que no primeiro exemplo, os : estão implícitos e, no segundo exemplo, estão explícitos.

Veja alguns tutoriais a respeito:

http://guru-sp.github.io/tutorial_ruby/simbolos.html

http://www.akitaonrails.com/2007/11/26/ruby-symbols